# How to get last six month data from database by month base

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I tried with calender instant and for loop like

```
for(int i = 6; i >= 0; --i){
    GraphDto graphDto=new GraphDto();

    Calendar c2=Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.add(Calendar.MONTH,-i);
    c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    graphDto.setLabel(getMonth(c2.get(Calendar.MONTH)));

    Date fromDate1=c2.getTime();
    c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
    c2.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    Date toDate1=c2.getTime();
    Double value1=billHistoryRepository.findAmount(fromDate1,toDate1);
    Double value2=paymentHistoryRepository.findAmount(fromDate1,toDate1);
    c2.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);

    if(value1!=null) {
        graphDto.setValue1(value1);
    }
    if(value2!=null) {
        graphDto.setValue2(value2);
        graphDtoList.add(graphDto);
    }
}
```

it takes too much time and repeatedly calling the repository. is there any other method to find out, like jdbc query or something

Comment: Have you taken a look at this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods?

Comment: Can't you just get the data from the last 6 months at once and then group it by each month afterwards in the Java code?

Answer (score 0):

I got the way..

select DATE_FORMAT(`created_date`,'%M %Y') as Month,sum(amount) from bill_history group by month(created_date) limit 6;

Result will be

Month       |sum(amount)

June 2016   |      129388

July 2016   |    22723419

August 2016 |    525004.4